# table cell, wrapped text, fit width to content, remove extra right hand white space

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, css-tables

I have a set width table container, it will contain 3 text elements separated by single characters (>).
These text elements may contain text that cannot be fit in the container on a single line along with the rest, and must be wrapped.

The issue is when the text wraps, the cell will contain extra white space on the right hand side that then forces the other elements to wrap, where normally, without the white space, the succeeding elements would each fit on a single line.

Here is the desired behavior:

[image]

Where the first text element cannot fit on a single line and must wrap.

But any of the other text elements may also not fit on a single line and must wrap, leaving no extra white space.

Using a basic table layout:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Membership Clubs and Organizations</td>
      <td>></td>
      <td>Books Wholesaler</td>
      <td>></td>
      <td>Music Management</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.table {
  width:450px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

Here there is extra whitespace, causing the succeeding elements to also wrap.

After a lot of research, the closest i have come is by setting width:0.1% for the text elements.
Unfortunately this results in the separating characters having their own extra white space, which i have not been able to remove, i have been unable to reduce their width to fit their contents.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text">Membership Clubs and Organizations</td>
      <td class="separator">></td>
      <td class="text">Books Wholesaler</td>
      <td class="separator">></td>
      <td class="text">Music Management</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.text {
  width:0.1%;
}
.table {
  width:450px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

I settled on using tables because it got me closer to what i need, but i am open to use any format, the only requirement is that it be in pure css, and not use any javascript.

```css
.text {
  width:0.1%;
}
.table {
  width:450px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text">Membership Clubs and Organizations</td>
      <td class="separator">></td>
      <td class="text">Books Wholesaler</td>
      <td class="separator">></td>
      <td class="text">Music Management</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The width of the table is forcing the white-space to be there, no matter what. table-cells have extra space, so the words wrap when necessary, or the cells have no extra space, so the words wrap on every word.

I think the only option for zero whitespace is

```
td { word-break: break-all; }
```

```css
.table {
  width:450px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text">Membership Clubs and Organizations</td>
      <td class="separator">></td>
      <td class="text">Books Wholesaler</td>
      <td class="separator">></td>
      <td class="text">Music Management</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did consider that option, unfortunately it affects readability too much. If that's the only option, including using something other than tables, then i'd probably just present it some other way.

Comment: Yeah, the width will affect when/where words break. If those are guaranteed to be the only words used, and you can guarantee the font, and font-size, etc., you might get away with setting exact widths, for a while...

Comment: Is there a way to do it if the table isn't a fixed minimum size? i could wrap it in a container with a fixed size and size the table on the content. If that might work.

Comment: Any fixed-size container will affect the wrapping. A long word like 'Organizations' will wrap if there is not enough room for it, and you will end up with white-space. Long words are a problem unless you can break them. If you can use hyphens when the word breaks, then that's an option. I can't remember off the top if that can be done with css only.

Comment: If you use `white-space: nowrap;` on the `td`s, you might get close, but the table will be as wide as all of the words combined on one line. With those headers, it will be around 550px i think.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it will use varying texts of varying lengths so, i think i will just need to use a different way to present it.

Comment: If you go back to your first code-sample and center the text it would look good. Ciao.

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
.text {
  width:0.1%;
}
```